# How to input selected characters of password using selenium c# webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2013

I need to write the c# Selenium code for the login function of a website.

The user is prompted to enter three different characters from their password for example 3rd, 6th and 8th characters, each in separate text fields; the characters requested will change each time the user attempts to login, as a result I'm struggling to automate.  In my test environment the password is always set to TestPassword

The HTML assigns an Id to the text field in relation to the character requested for example below is the request for the 5th character. This is the same for every other character however, the number changes to represent the character of the password requested.

```
<div class="form-type-password form-item-password-challenge-challenges-5 form-item form-group">
<label for="edit-password-challenge-challenges-5">
5
<sup>th</sup>
</label>
<input id="edit-password-challenge-challenges-5" class="form-control form-text" type="password" maxlength="1" size="1" name="password_challenge[challenges][5]" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" placeholder="-"/
```

It is possible to be asked for characters 1 to 10. Is it possible to automate this using Selenium in C#?

Many thanks

Comment: So, do you have to enter *5* if the html contains *5*?

Comment: No, I have to enter the fifth character of the password, as the password is always set to TestPassword in the test environment I would have to enter P. Thanks for your reply

Comment: So, I am assuming if the html contains *6* then you need to enter *a* to the input box?

Comment: So take your "TestPassword" convert it to a byte array, and pick the appropriate byte from that array. Which part of that is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you.

```
 //Your password string
const string testPassword = "TestPassword";
//find the id attribute that contains the index of character needs to be input
string str= driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[id^='edit-password-challenge']")).GetAttribute("id");
//find the index of the char
int index = Convert.ToInt16(Regex.Match(str, "[0-9]+").ToString().Replace("\"", ""));
//find the char and convert to string so that can be used with SendKeys() method
string charToInput = testPassword[index-1].ToString();

//input the password using the SendKeys() method
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("the selector")).SendKeys(charToInput);
```